# keep largest value in a range R

Tags: r

Example code:

```
x <- c(10,15,21,24,32,48,56,78,87,98)
y <- c(2,3,4,5,2.1,3.1,1,1.5,1.9,2.6)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df
```

Sorry im relatively new to coding.  I got some help last night narrowing a large data frame down by finding the largest Y for every 10 unit segment, but it turns out that could lead to errors.

I apologize I am still relatively new to programming in general.

So, I have a threshold value of say, y > 1.91.  How can I find the largest Y given a range of 10 units in X?  So, my thinking is that I would find max(y) > threshold then delete all x rows within 10 units.  Then find 2nd highest y (must be greater than threshold) and delete all x within 10 unit.  I would do this until I have a list of all values that are above threshold and atleast 10 units from each other.

Can you guys help me code this?

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, you nearly are writing valid code in your question - R is interactive. Try something and see what the result is - then try combining that with other bits of code. E.g. you know what `max(y)` gives, you can see what `y > 1.91` gives, you can probably guess what `y[y > 1.91]` gives... etc... etc...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the output to be, given your example `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
threshold <- 1.91
dt <- dt[y>threshold, ]
ans <- dt[0,]

while (nrow(dt)>0){
  ans <- rbindlist(list(ans, dt[which.max(y),]))
  xval <- ans[nrow(ans),x]
  dt <- dt[x<(xval-10)|x>(xval+10)]
}
ans
```